# Sum of difference between array elements

Tags: c, arrays

I need to calculate the difference between array elements (only if the next element is greater than the previous) and return the sum of these differences with the first array element.

```
3
1 5 6
ans = 1 + [5-1] + [6-5] = 6
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long long int T, N, M[100000], i, j, diff[100000];
  int sum = 0;
  scanf("%lld", &T);

  while (T--) {
    scanf("%lld", &N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      scanf("%lld", &M[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
      if (M[i] < M[i+1]) {
        diff[i] = M[i+1] - M[i];
        sum = sum + diff[i];
      }
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum + M[0]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: only first test case is showing correct output rest all i am getting incorrect output

Comment: What are the failing test cases?

Comment: input  test cases= 4
 no of elements= 4
  elements in array=1 2 1 5                                                                                                 output  6
          11
          16
           21                                                                                                     output must be 6 6 6 6

Comment: for latter three test cases also input is same no of elements =4  and elements in array =1 2 1 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're not resetting `sum` to zero for each iteration of `T`. Thus, it incorrectly retains the sum from the previous test case on subsequent test cases.

You can fix this by setting `sum = 0;` at the start of the `while(T--)` loop.

---

Also, here's how I would rewrite this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef long long int num_t;
#define NUMFMT "%lld"

int main() {

    num_t T;
    scanf(NUMFMT,&T);
    while (T--) {
        num_t N;
        scanf(NUMFMT,&N);
        if (N < 1) { fprintf(stderr, "error: require at least one number.\n" ); exit(1); }
        N--;
        num_t M1;
        scanf(NUMFMT,&M1);
        num_t sum = M1;
        while (N--) {
            num_t M2;
            scanf(NUMFMT,&M2);
            if (M1 < M2)
                sum += M2-M1;
            M1 = M2;
        } // end while
        printf(NUMFMT"\n",sum);
    } // end while

    return 0;

} // end main()
```

Demo:

```
ls;
## acus.c
gcc acus.c -o acus;
ls;
## acus.c  acus*
./acus;
## 6
## 1 5
## 5
## 3 1 2 3
## 3
## 3 3 2 1
## 3
## 3 1 5 6
## 6
## 4 6 4 2 3
## 7
## 0
## error: require at least one number.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should really be in code review...

Your code reads T, and through the loop destroys its value. Do yourself and the reader a favour and call the variable "numberOfTestCases", and then do a loop for (long long testCase = 0; testCase < numberOfTestCases; ++testCase) ... That's the standard way to write a loop. And believe me, longer variable names don't slow down the code.

You declared M as long long int, and sum as int. Now think about it: Even in the most trivial case where M [0] = 0 and M [1] > 0, if M [1] is big then it won't fit into an int. This absolutely doesn't make sense. The values that sum holds must be the same or larger than those that M holds.

You declared and initialised sum outside the loop for the test cases. You probably learned that a variable should always be initialised. WRONG. The initialisation here just hides a fatal bug, and that is that you don't reset sum to 0 again. You should have declared sum inside your loop, just for one test case. Declaring and initialising it outside the loop was a bug waiting to happen.

The diff array is completely pointless. You are just wasting 800KB of memory. The variable j is never used, which is confusing.

You are using one declaration for various items whose type is not related. The type of T should be based on the maximum number of test sets that you need to process. The type of N and i should be based on the maximum number of values in a test. The type of M should be based on the requirement how large the input values could be. These three types are unrelated, still you use one declaration. "Accident waiting to happen".

Your app is going to crash if N > 100,000 or N = LLONG_MIN.

You put all your functionality into main (). That's not what main is there for. main () should set up your application and start things. Most likely main () should call a function do_homework, and do_homework should call functions read_data, and calculate_sum.

Comment: i understood my mistakes and i executed  i will keep in mind next time thanks for info. .And yes I am just a novice in programming.